# Conditionally changing date format of a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I'm working with a list with length 20. And I have sheets (list) with different formats, like this:

List.1 # In this case with a correct format

```
Id  DATE
1   2019/02/01
2   2019/02/04
3   2019/02/04
```

List.2 # With a wrong format

```
Id  DATE
4   42586
5   42587
6   45590
```

I would like to correct the format of list.2 as the list.1 format

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:20) {
DF[[i]]$DATA=as.Date.numeric(as.numeric(as.character(DF[[i]]$DATA)),origin = "1899-12-30")
}
```

So, didn't work, my function didn't select the sheets with the problem, but all of them.

Comment: use ifelse with string detect ?

Comment: As currently written, you are applying `as.Date(., origin = "1899-12-30")` to every sheet. To handle both date formats, you need to first check what format the date is in, and then apply the appropriate date conversion based on that result. You could use regular expressions to check which format of date you have

Answer (score -1):

(using lubridate)
If you know exactly the original reference date, I would:

- Detect if the value is numeric
- If so, reduce the number of days from 1899-12-30 to 1970-01-01 (default for starting)
- Use the lubridate as_date function to read the output of the above